# What is the proper way to acess data inside y_true and y_pred inside a custom loss function for Keras ( Tensorflow Backend)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

### I am creating a custom loss in Keras with Tensorflow backend.

### Inside Lossfunction extracting part of array is not working

(this is my first post, i am trying to hit the standards:))

My input is an array of 80x80x1 matrices (as x_train)

The loss function should do some calculations on the predicted parameters and the input. 
The Result of this calculations is the loss to minimize.

### The Problem:

the `y_true` inside the custom loss : 
`y_true` shape: [batch 80 80 1]

Te question is, how can i get the 80x80 back from `y_true` . The following code is not working:

```
extracted_data_80x80 = y_true[ 0, :, :, 0]
```

The corresponding errormessage is the following:

```
ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 2; input has only 2 dims for 'loss/dense_3_loss/strided_slice_7' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [?,?], [4], [4], [4] and with computed input tensors: input[3] = <1 1 1 1>.
```

### The Examplecode:

```
# -------
# Import
# -------
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# -----------------------
# Generating random input
# 100 pices of 8x8 array
# -----------------------
X_train = np.random.rand(10000,8,8)
y_train = np.random.rand(10000,8,8)

# Here we add an additional Dimension to be able to work with
# Keras Conv2D (maybe this step is the origin of the problem)
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=4)
y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=4)


# -----------------
# The Loss Function
# -----------------
def CustomLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    #y_true[batch, 8, 8, 1] 

    # Extracting the 8x8 part from y_true
    extracted_data_80x80  = y_true[0, :, :, 0] # This is NOT working   

    return tf.reduce_sum(extracted_data_80x80 )


# -----------
# Keras Model
# -----------
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten

model = Sequential()

# add model layers
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", input_shape=(8, 8, 1),data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3, activation="relu"))

# compile model using *CustomLoss* as loss
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss = CustomLoss)

#train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=2, verbose=1)
```

**So i am really woundering what would be here the correct way to extract the 80x80 part of the Tensor?**

Thank you for your time, your help and saving my life :)

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Example added in "Example code" section

Comment: It is still not verifiable and minimal. Put yourself in our position: You are interested in the slicing part. So for us to be able to debug it, we would need an example tensor that does not work in a copy-pasteable form. Also most of your post could be omitted for brevity's sake.

Comment: Hi feliks, i have reduced what i could, and the question is reformatted.
what do you mean under:
 " example tensor that does not work in a copy-pasteable form" ?